# Mocking node.js dependency prototype methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, testing, jestjs

I'm having difficulty mocking an external dependency in node.js (ts-node) with Jest (ts-jest). The dependency is `node-chargebee` (https://github.com/chargebee/chargebee-node).

The lib exports all its endpoints in a prototype class `new RequestWrapper()` and the method attached to this I want to mock (the method that calls the chargebee API server) is `.request()` (i.e. `RequestWrapper.prototype.request = function(callBack, envOptions)`).

So a full call on `node-chargebee` would be like

```
chargebee.plan.retrieve("id").request((result, error) => {...})
```

As I say, I'm trying to mock the `.request()` and I'm sure I'm being stupid in not knowing how to do this and missing something really simple?

In short, I simply want to avoid actual calls to `request()` and either ignore the response or stub the `(result, error)` response out?

For a little more understanding, the important parts of the `node-chargebee` lib are:

```
function createApiFunc(apiCall) {
  return function() {
    return new RequestWrapper(arguments, apiCall);
  };
}

function RequestWrapper(args, apiCall) {
  this.args = args;
  this.httpHeaders = {};
  this.apiCall = apiCall;
  if (this.apiCall.hasIdInUrl) {
    validateIdParam(this.args[0]);
  }
}

RequestWrapper.prototype.request = function(callBack, envOptions) {
  ...
  ChargeBee._core.makeApiRequest(...)
}

(function() {
  for (var res in ChargeBee._endpoints) {
    module.exports[res] = {};
    var apiCalls = ChargeBee._endpoints[res];
    for (var apiIdx = 0; apiIdx < apiCalls.length; apiIdx++) {
      ...
      module.exports[res][apiCall.methodName] = createApiFunc(apiCall);
    }
  }
})();
```

Example snippet of the `ChargeBee._endpoints` looks like:

```
var _endpoints = {
  "subscription": [
    [
      "create",
      "POST",
      "/subscriptions",
      null,
      false
    ],
    [
      "create_for_customer",
      "POST",
      "/customers",
      "/subscriptions",
      true
    ],
    [
      "list",
      "GET",
      "/subscriptions",
      null,
      false
    ],
    [
      "subscriptions_for_customer",
      "GET",
      "/customers",
      "/subscriptions",
      true
    ],
    [
      "retrieve",
      "GET",
      "/subscriptions",
      null,
      true
    ],
    ...
}
```